# Must I add a WCF service class library in order to host a WCF Service in a Windows service?

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I read about how to host Wcf Service in a Windows service. There is a guide here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

But what I did was just to create new WCF Service class and interface inside the same project of the Windows Service instead of creating a new project separatly for the Wcf service.
Is it possible to do it? because I can't add a service reference to that service from other projects in the solution. It can't find it.

Comment: Yes, you can use a WCF Service Library and host it in a Windows Service.  But in order to add a service reference the Windows Service will need to be running.

Comment: I ran the service doing "start without debugging"  but it doesn't find the endpoint when I'm trying to add a service reference. I don't understand your comment. Must I create a class library for the Wcf service? or I can add a class of Wcf service to the existing windows service?

Comment: You can't run a Windows Service through Visual Studio like you can other projects (console, web, WinForms, etc).  You have to install the Windows Service and start it.  *Then* you should be able to add a reference.

Comment: OK, I will try it, although I found a way in the past to run windows service through vs, after making few changes to the code, and I use this way.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10153/Debugging-Windows-Services-under-Visual-Studio-NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is what I found.

1. Creating a new solution with one Windows service project with a Wcf service class and one Asp.Net folder.
2. Running the Windows service.
3. Trying to add a Service reference to the Asp.Net project.

Result: Service can't be found.

1. Adding a new project which contains a Wcf project to the solution.
2. Adding a reference to it from the Windows Service.
3. Trying to add a Service reference to the Asp.Net project.

Result: Service found.

Reading this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx it's done similar to what I did in the test solution, but still there is a need to write some code in the Windows Service.

In this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx

They show how to host it without creating a separate project.

So the answer to the question is no, you must not, but you have to write some code for hosting the service and can't just use the configuration file.

Note the windows service must be running so you can successfully add the reference.